# Have Microsoft rewritten Windows Workflow Foundation in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation

I heard from a friend that Microsoft rewrote all the Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) again and changed everything was in .Net 3.5.

Is that true?

And what about what we learned about WF in 3.0 and 3.5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this article:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/01/01/windows-workflow-changes-direction.aspx

Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 is a "bottom-up rewrite with entirely new thinking...WF 3.0/3.5 will remain part of the framework and will run side by side with WF 4.0. This lets you manage the transition at a time that fits your organization's broader goals."

...which is code for, "We know we just screwed up your programming model, but we have a long term strategy, so we hope you will forgive us."

The article goes on to say that

> The gains are enormous: custom
>   activities take center stage, and
>   authoring them is much simpler;
>   workflows are entirely declarative;
>   and there are three workflow flow
>   styles that you can combine
>   seamlessly. It's possible that you
>   could see a 10-fold improvement in the
>   time required to create and debug
>   workflows, in addition to 10- to
>   100-fold runtime performance
>   improvements.

The change is not without its detractors.  In [this article at DotNetKicks](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/wwf/Windows_Workflow_a_total_rewrite_in_Dot_Net_4_0), the author states that "Microsoft is seriously damaging the Dot Net developer community and adoption in the industry with these half baked product releases and abrupt about-faces after shipping."

Which is why I generally wait for the 2.0 or 3.0 version of Microsoft technologies, although I made an exception for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that they called the initial WWF 'lightweight' too. Anything W*F is anything but, and instead of fixing and enhancing basics like JIT, WinForms rendering, and rendering in general on previous OS version. they just keep piling on bloat after bloat. It's simply not in their interest to keep things good, decent and stable, but they'll advocate new promises every-single-time. Congratulations to them, but things like that make people walk away over time, and away from lock-in for sure.

Comment: What about the jitter needs fixing or enhancing?  And WinForms rendering was improved--its called WPF.  And increasing the number of frameworks available to use is NOT bloat.  You don't want to use WF?  Don't use it.  Go look up the definition of "bloat".  Also, saying that its not in their interest to keep things good, decent and stable has to be about the stupidest thing I've heard.  They profit from having a bad, unstable platform?  On its face its ridiculous.  Please, keep this kind of nonsense on /.

Comment: Just saw this one in the list of my highest upvoted comments and lol'd.  Aah, those were the days.

Comment: lol. well I guess the main alternative(Java) is so much better.. Being as it is completely bloat free, has unbelievable forms, and never suffers from version inpcompatibility issues between runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

We found the workflow product to be difficult to wrap your head around when it came time to pass data in and out.  Scott Allen had a series of articles that did a good job describing the process, but still this was not at an easy task.

Comment: Are you talking about 3.5 or 4.0? As seen above, 4.0 is a rewrite and redesign - most of what you learned in 3.0/3.5 is out the window for 4.0.

Comment: 3.5  What sucks is that what we've learned / experimented with in respects to WF and SharePoint is now in question.  In some cases we've scrapped WF and used Stateless from Nicholas Blumhardt.  With Stateless we had a State Machine incorporated into our app with in a half hour.  WF State Machine was almost 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [word on the street](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2008/11/microsoft-rewrites-workflow-foundation.html) is.  And on the [internet](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/01/01/windows-workflow-changes-direction.aspx).  3.0 and 3.5 will be deprecated, but still available.

Answer (score 0):

Is this change not in Visual Studio 2010 beta 1? Download it, find out, and tell Microsoft what you think of it.